# English description of a bought bottle with strange words

Tags: word-meaning

I bought a special bottle to keep my drinkable yogurt in a safe place.

There is a section in the product description saying:

> Do not use detergent containing **bieach** or **abradant** and any other rough
>   material to clean this product.

I understood what they wanted to say, because we have similar words, in Italian, but i tried to search on the internet and it looks like in english they don't exist at all except for abradant which appears in some minor translators but not in the most famous

I would like to understand if there is something missing.

Abradant is something abrasive as i understood but bieach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing something! It's most likely ***bleach***, not ***bieach***. It would be common for special, sensitive containers to have warnings about harmful chemicals. Bleach would be a chemical that would likely cause harm to rubber, plastic, and metal. I'm curious to know if they misspelled the word on the container, or if a fleck of yogurt obscured the "l" in bleach.

Comment: I don't know if it's a spelling error but they wrote bieach ahah, anyway i suppose they wanted to say bleach

Answer (score 4):

Instead of *bieach*, what they probably mean is *[bleach](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bleach)* (a chemical for making materials whiter). An *[abradant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abradant)* is simply something that is abrasive.